# What's the correct way to handle Alias variable?

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I'm running a logistic regression & got the error message

```
Error in vif.default(failure.survival.train) : 
there are aliased coefficients in the model
```

My equation that was generating above message was

```
group.survival.train = glm(group ~ .,family = binomial(logit), data =   group.train)
group_train_vif=vif(group.survival.train)
```

So, I try following things

```
alias( glm(group ~ .,family = binomial(logit), data = group.train) )
```

So I got following output

```
           (Intercept) group1 group2 group3 group4 group5 group6 group9
group7         0           0    0       0      0     0      0      0         
group8         0           0    0       0      0     0      0      0
```

Does this mean that Group 7 & 8 are linear dependent of Group 1-2-3-4-5-6-9 & I need to remove both group 7 & 8 from my model?

Comment: Here is a possible explanation, this link may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/45971359/11001997

Comment: Hi @MLS, thanks for the link.It's telling that Nonzero entries in the "complete" matrix show that those terms are linearly dependent & need to be removed. But in my case group7 & group 8 contains only 0 entries. Initially I removed group 7 from my data & ran the logistic regression again but got the same error. Then I kept group 7 & removed group 8, again got the same error message. After removing both 7 & 8 together that error message disappeared. Can you please guide me?